# import multiple xml files in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi all I was wondering if anyone might have any insight on this. Bear with with as im pretty new sql server and learning as I go.

I have a folder `(C:\xml_files\)` which contains about more than 100 xml files. I was wondering if there is a way to upload all the files within this folder and display them in a table where each row represents the results of a different file. All the xml files are formatted the same.

I am currently using MS Sql Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say following is the structure of your xml file:

```
<Books>
  <Book>
    <Title>Abzc</Title>
    <Pages>207</Pages>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <Title>xyz</Title>
    <Pages>312</Pages>
  </Book>
  <Book>
   <Title>ghj</Title>
   <Pages>123</Pages>
  </Book>
</Books>
```

So you can use the following code to store it in a database:

```
declare @count int, @filename varchar(20)
set @count=1
while @count<4
begin  

   select @filename=filename from test4 where id=@count
   EXEC('INSERT INTO Books (Title, Book_Pages)
    select c3.value(''Title[1]'',''VARCHAR(100)''),
    c3.value(''Pages[1]'',''int'')  from(
    select  cast(c1 as xml)
    FROM OPENROWSET(
     BULK '''+@filename+''',SINGLE_BLOB) as T1(c1)
    )as T2(c2)
cross apply c2.nodes(''/Books/Book'') T3(c3)');
    set @count=@count+1
end
```

Comment: Thats close but the files are all named different, how would I be able to loop through all the files

Comment: Declare a temporary table with all the file name. Put this code inside a while loop, and declare  a variable to hold the file names. this would solve the purpose.

Comment: Thank you sonam, but can you give me an example code, im not sure how to go about and perform this, im sorry im a noob with sql server

Comment: I've edited my answer with the updated code.